# Sync Google Spreadsheet on Google Drive with QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-drive, interface

I have different apps created with Appsheet which store the reported data in Google Spreadsheets on Google Drive. The data is spatial (having lat and long, though in the same column, comma-separated). Now I'd like to sync between the reported data stored on Google Drive and QGIS, because I do a lot of analysing work in QGIS. I also do have photos saved on Google Drive which are linked to the reported points by ID in separate columns of the Spreadsheet.

Does someone have experience with this topic or any useful tipps?

I'm not really good in programming though...probably it's still the best way.